# Power BI-Customer purchase count

Tags: database, count, powerbi

I need to detect the number of customers who make purchases in the 2 stores with a single formula

data:
[image]
Result:
1 Person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this below measure-

```
person_count = 

var total_shop_count = DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Shop])

var tab = 
SUMMARIZE(
    your_table_name,
    your_table_name[Name],
    "shop_count",DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[Shop])
)

return 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        tab,
        [shop_count] = total_shop_count
    )
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]